# Add mapping in AWS API Gateway to DynamoDB query with Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I'm reading https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/aws/api-gateway/ documentation
and its not quite clear how to use custom integrations, since AWS requires their proprietary template.
I need to map HTTP GET request to DynamoDB query and want to do that without extra Lambda function, using mapping in API gateway. 
Is there an example or test unit of how to achieve that in Pulumi (or using crosswalk library)?

Comment: I suspect crosswalk won't help here, you might want to use `aws.apigateway.Integration` https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/aws/apigateway/#Integration

Comment: Great tutorial (but does not use Pulumi):  https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0